# Why doesn't my styled ToggleButton work on the second tab of a TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, tabcontrol

I encountered a problem when I was developing a WPF application with a TabControl object. I tried to debug and find the problem and finally I've got it, but I didn't find any workaround to it. Here is some explanation:

I used this data grid filtering library ([here is a codeproject url](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42227/Automatic-WPF-Toolkit-DataGrid-Filtering)), which is the best (from my viewpoint). I want to customize it with the google material design theme and change some graphical features, such as using a toggle button in the first tab header of data gird to hide/show the filtering option.

I created a user control and placed my custom datagrid in it. Then I embedded that control into the tabItem. When I set this control to the first tabItem, everything works correctly. But when I change the user control to the other tabItem, the toggle button does not work.

Here is my main window xaml code that didn't work:

```
 <TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
        <TabItem Header="1'st Tab">
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                <Button Content="Do no thing"></Button>
            </ContentControl>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="2'nd Tab">
            <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                <local:UserControl1/>
            </ContentControl>
        </TabItem>
 </TabControl>
```

Note that if I change the order of TabItems, it works well. Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this problem? [Here is my sample project code on Github](https://github.com/alr2413/Material-Design-Data-Grid-with-Filtering-Options-WPF-)

[image: Control was placed in the first tab]
[image: Control was placed in the other tab]

Edit: Today, I test my application with "WPF Inspector" to find the structure of visual and logical tree. The behavior was too strange because when I attached "WPF Inspector" to my application, everything started to work. The below GIF is what I did:

[image: Strange behavior GIF]

Comment: Welcome to SO! I changed the title of your question. Please refer to the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to get informed whether you should use tags in the question title. You should also provide us with a [mcve] rather than just posting links to external code.

Comment: There is no difference between these two codes. You should only change the order of a TabItem in a TabControl. Nevertheless, I'll add some lines of code. I appreciate your offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a `ContentControl` for a Data-Object, in your case it's the data context, you bind the `Content` property to the Data-Object and specify the `DataTemplate` property. In this case the content within `DataTemplate` will have its `DataContext` set to your Data-Object.

Here is a working sample:

```
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
        <TabItem Header="1'st Tab">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding .}">
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Do no thing"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentControl>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="2'nd Tab">
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding .}">
                <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:UserControl1/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
            </ContentControl>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```